# Ordering a Grouped Result in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following LINQ query that I use to group on all the employees.

```
var groups =
  from employee in employees
  group employee by employee.ReportsTo;
```

The link returns an IGrouping object.

I would now like to order this result using the ReportsTo, where ReportsTo is the name of the manager of each employee. How can I acheive this using C#? Is this possible?

Comment: Did you mean I would "now" like to.... instead of I would not like to ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var groups = from employee in employees
             group employee by employee.ReportsTo into g
             orderby g.Key
             select g;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather write it like this as it is more "readable"

```
var groups = employees.GroupBy(employee => employee.ReportsTo).OrderBy(group => group.Key)
```